# show primeng menuitem only when authenticated

Tags: angular, jhipster, primeng

Has anyone a working example of how to create a primeNG menu that hides certain items if the user is not logged in? There is the 'visible' and 'disabled' attribute but simply calling isAuthenticated doesn't change anything. Subscribing to state change such as

```
visible: this.principal.getAuthenticationState().subscribe((value) => this.principal.isAuthenticated())
```

gives me an error:

```
TS2322: Type '({ label: string; icon: string; items: ({ label: string; icon: string; command: (event: any) => v...' is not assignable to type 'MenuItem[]'.
```

Comment: have you tried using simple ngIf or ngSwith? It's better than controlling visibility because the dom element is not created at all.

Comment: no I havent. how would you do it? according to the docs you simply add "<p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>" so I felt everything else has to be done in typescript code ...

Comment: This is pure Angular, this is why it is not included in primeng docs, try enclosing your element within a span and use ngIf on it.

Comment: it does work that way if I dynamically build the items tree, it is somewhat  cumbersome doing it like this. however it works, thx!